# Is it possible to connect a laptop to a Linux desktop - to function as the desktop console?

Tags: linux, usb, console

I have some 30 Linux (RHEL/CentOS 7) desktops that operate as servers.
Their only connections are power and NIC.
Being desktops, most don't have serial ports.

How can I go about using a Linux laptop to serve as their console?
I'm thinking of connecting the laptop to the desktop with a USB-to-USB cable.

1. Is the above possible?
2. What software (hardware?) would I need on the
   laptop (desktop?) to enable it to serve as a console?

### Edit:

I need the console to work at *all* stages of a power-up, e.g. - at the *BIOS* stage.
Thus, any solutions that rely on the Linux kernel being up and running would not work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are products that serve to enable a laptop as a portable KVM device. They are commonly used for lightweight/portable crash carts. Start here: https://www.google.com/search?q=usb+crash+cart+adapter

As we don't do product recommendations, I can't be much more specific than that. Those types of answers don't age well. But this sort of thing is often made by companies like StarTech, IOGEAR, Tripplite, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, @Aaron. And, even though most  _KVM Console to USB_ solutions seem to require a VGA port on the debugged machine, I found few that will use HDMI/DVI (as I mentioned, my machines are desktops, whose motherboards mostly do not include a VGA port, but instead, they include HDMI and DVI ports).

Answer (score 1):

Being desktops I assume Xorg is running on those machines.
In that case you can simply use VNC.

Install tigervnc-server on all your servers, and tigervnc on your client and set them up with local users (although, again, being desktops you probably already have a user that starts X)

this will allow you to connect to all your machines while JUST using the network instead of dealing with additional cables connect/disconnect.

**IF** you don't have Xorg running, then it's not necessary for you to do all this, via SSH you can manage your machine easily.

```
    ssh user@host -c "systemctl start httpd.service"
```

You can even work with additional machines with Systemctl (since you speak of CentOS7)

```
    systemctl --host user@host start httpd.service
```

**These both work via ssh starting `httpd.service` on the host `host` with user `user`**

Also with systemd-journal-remote you can share journal entries between hosts, but it's a bit more complex to set up, with `--listen-http` you can passively wait for entries and then `-o` output them somewhere on your local machine.

#### RHEL Documentation on these subjects, FYI:

VNC Client & Server from scratch: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/ch-tigervnc#sec-terminating-vnc-session
VNC Existing Server: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sec-vnc-sharing-an-existing-desktop
VNC Existing Client: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sec-vnc-viewer

systemd-journal-remote: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-journal-remote.service.html

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, @MatteoBee: see my *Edit* in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to ssh to the machinse via terminal. But I think what you want is to plug the laptop and act as KVM... why not just put monitor? and keyboard?

Comment: your suggestion is impractical for me - in terms of access: I have no easy access to the back of the machines, and connecting/disconnecting a screen to the back of a debugged machine is quite unworkable.

Comment: You want it to work from power on/BIOS. You're going to need to plug something in. Period.